# Hidden left nav looks weird (blue linkish design)

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, left-nav

Previously the left nav hidden in the topbar had the same black layout as the uncollapsed nav. However recently they turned into some strange bluish/link color. I don't think this is intentional:

[image: Invalid behavior: Blue link color]

[image: Correct behavior when uncollapsed]

Issue occuring on all sites I tested.

Comment: The team tried to standardize on all links being the same color for consistency with [their design framework](https://stackoverflow.design/). I agree that this looks weird and is an unfortunate regression. There was a related bug on Meta Stack Overflow with the Community Bulletin links being odd colors.

Comment: And now that's fixed but the site switcher (on the right end of the top bar) has messed-up link colors.  The bug migrated! :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now:

[image: Blue turns to gray. Problem fixed.]

Also confirmed on desktop computer.